# Auth email in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication, django-settings

I am making my first app, which is a todolist app. I am trying to get users to register with email and login with it.

This is the error that the debug shows me:

```
ProgrammingError at /register/

no existe la relación «core_user»
LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" =...
                             ^

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version:     5.0.2
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

no existe la relación «core_user»
LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "core_user" WHERE "core_user"."email" =...
```

My files have the following configuration

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['complete']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, FormView

from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from django.contrib.auth import login

from .models import Task
from .forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'core/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    redirect_authenticated_user = True

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('task_list')

class RegisterPage(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/register.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
        return super(RegisterPage, self).form_valid(form)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('task_list')
        return super(RegisterPage, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'core/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'task_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['task_list'] = context['task_list'].filter(user=self.request.user)
        context['count'] = context['task_list'].filter(complete=False).count()

        search_input = self.request.GET.get('search-area') or ''
        if search_input:
            context['task_list'] = context['task_list'].filter(title__startswith=search_input)

        context['search_input'] = search_input

        return context

class TaskDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'core/task_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'task'

class TaskCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'core/task_form.html'
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'complete']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(TaskCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class TaskUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'complete']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

class TaskDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'task'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import forms


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Email')

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        # Verificar si el nombre de usuario es un correo electrónico
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}

        # Asignar los datos limpios validados al formulario
        self.cleaned_data['username'] = username
        self.cleaned_data['password'] = password
        return super().clean()
```

backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

UserModel = get_user_model()

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        except UserModel.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            # Podrías manejar este caso de manera más específica si es necesario
            user = UserModel.objects.filter(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username)).order_by('id').first()

        if user and check_password(password, user.password):
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for todolist_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-0blmoc@*qb)vl*b++oj$akhq!3@s^dhbq3u89nt3ap(%0%thd9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'core.backends.EmailBackend',  # Personalización para permitir inicio de sesión con email
]

# Personalización de la autenticación para permitir inicio de sesión con email
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'todolist_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'todolist_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'core.backends.EmailBackend',  # Personalización para permitir inicio de sesión con email
]

# Personalización de la autenticación para permitir inicio de sesión con email
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I want to be able to login and register correctly, without using the username, using email and password.

Comment: Likely you did not make migraitons or migrate.

Comment: Yes, I did makemigrations and migrate, both says me No changes detected and No migrations to apply, but I don't have folder migrations.

Comment: I don't know why this happens, maybe I should start the project again and do it from the beginning with email, since I used before the library provided by django. If I start the project again, is it better to separate the user authentication with a separate app for them? And then make another one where to put the tasks?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you've overridden the default behavior to use the email as the username, you should include 'email' in the REQUIRED_FIELDS list instead of 'username'.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

Comment: It's a mistake, thank you very much for correcting it and replying.